# I need to get data out of 2D array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, 2d

The total number of months included in the dataset.
The net total amount of Profit/Losses over the entire period.
The average of the **changes** in Profit/Losses over the entire period.
You will need to track what the total change in profits are from month to month and then find the average.

- (`Total/Number of months`)
- The greatest increase in profits (date and amount) over the entire period.
- The greatest decrease in losses (date and amount) over the entire period.

```
var finances = [
  ["Jan-2010", 867884],
  ["Feb-2010", 984655],
  ["Mar-2010", 322013],
  ["Apr-2010", -69417],
  ["May-2010", 310503],
  ["Jun-2010", 522857],
  ["Jul-2010", 1033096],
  ["Aug-2010", 604885],
  ["Sep-2010", -216386],
  ["Oct-2010", 477532],
  ["Nov-2010", 893810],
  ["Dec-2010", -80353],
  ["Jan-2011", 779806],
  ["Feb-2011", -335203],
  ["Mar-2011", 697845],
  ["Apr-2011", 793163],
  ["May-2011", 485070],
  ["Jun-2011", 584122],
  ["Jul-2011", 62729],
  ["Aug-2011", 668179],
  ["Sep-2011", 899906],
  ["Oct-2011", 834719],
  ["Nov-2011", 132003],
  ["Dec-2011", 309978],
  ["Jan-2012", -755566],
  ["Feb-2012", 1170593],
  ["Mar-2012", 252788],
  ["Apr-2012", 1151518],
  ["May-2012", 817256],
  ["Jun-2012", 570757],
  ["Jul-2012", 506702],
  ["Aug-2012", -1022534],
  ["Sep-2012", 475062],
  ["Oct-2012", 779976],
  ["Nov-2012", 144175],
  ["Dec-2012", 542494],
  ["Jan-2013", 359333],
  ["Feb-2013", 321469],
  ["Mar-2013", 67780],
  ["Apr-2013", 471435],
  ["May-2013", 565603],
  ["Jun-2013", 872480],
  ["Jul-2013", 789480],
  ["Aug-2013", 999942],
  ["Sep-2013", -1196225],
  ["Oct-2013", 268997],
  ["Nov-2013", -687986],
  ["Dec-2013", 1150461],
  ["Jan-2014", 682458],
  ["Feb-2014", 617856],
  ["Mar-2014", 824098],
  ["Apr-2014", 581943],
  ["May-2014", 132864],
  ["Jun-2014", 448062],
  ["Jul-2014", 689161],
  ["Aug-2014", 800701],
  ["Sep-2014", 1166643],
  ["Oct-2014", 947333],
  ["Nov-2014", 578668],
  ["Dec-2014", 988505],
  ["Jan-2015", 1139715],
  ["Feb-2015", 1029471],
  ["Mar-2015", 687533],
  ["Apr-2015", -524626],
  ["May-2015", 158620],
  ["Jun-2015", 87795],
  ["Jul-2015", 423389],
  ["Aug-2015", 840723],
  ["Sep-2015", 568529],
  ["Oct-2015", 332067],
  ["Nov-2015", 989499],
  ["Dec-2015", 778237],
  ["Jan-2016", 650000],
  ["Feb-2016", -1100387],
  ["Mar-2016", -174946],
  ["Apr-2016", 757143],
  ["May-2016", 445709],
  ["Jun-2016", 712961],
  ["Jul-2016", -1163797],
  ["Aug-2016", 569899],
  ["Sep-2016", 768450],
  ["Oct-2016", 102685],
  ["Nov-2016", 795914],
  ["Dec-2016", 60988],
  ["Jan-2017", 138230],
  ["Feb-2017", 671099],
];
```

I don't understand how to do it, I'm new and I want to learn

Comment: Is this some kind of homework? There are so many ways to get this done, check 'for' loop, 'for...of' loop, '.map' method, '.filter' method, '.reduce' method.

Answer (score 0):

I did a little example to show to you the way, be free to adapt to your reality. The correct would be separate the function in another functions. I hope helped you, otherwise be free to ask me something. And stop using var, search and see the problems that may occur.
[A good exemple](https://dev.to/mindninjax/stop-using-var-for-declaring-variables-2p3a)

```js
const finances = [
  ["Jan-2010", 867884],
  ["Feb-2010", 984655],
  ["Mar-2010", 322013],
  ["Apr-2010", -69417],
  ["May-2010", 310503],
  ["Jun-2010", 522857],
  ["Jul-2010", 1033096],
  ["Aug-2010", 604885],
  ["Sep-2010", -216386],
  ["Oct-2010", 477532],
  ["Nov-2010", 893810],
  ["Dec-2010", -80353],
  ["Jan-2011", 779806],
  ["Feb-2011", -335203],
  ["Mar-2011", 697845],
  ["Apr-2011", 793163],
  ["May-2011", 485070],
  ["Jun-2011", 584122],
  ["Jul-2011", 62729],
  ["Aug-2011", 668179],
  ["Sep-2011", 899906],
  ["Oct-2011", 834719],
  ["Nov-2011", 132003],
  ["Dec-2011", 309978],
  ["Jan-2012", -755566],
  ["Feb-2012", 1170593],
  ["Mar-2012", 252788],
  ["Apr-2012", 1151518],
  ["May-2012", 817256],
  ["Jun-2012", 570757],
  ["Jul-2012", 506702],
  ["Aug-2012", -1022534],
  ["Sep-2012", 475062],
  ["Oct-2012", 779976],
  ["Nov-2012", 144175],
  ["Dec-2012", 542494],
  ["Jan-2013", 359333],
  ["Feb-2013", 321469],
  ["Mar-2013", 67780],
  ["Apr-2013", 471435],
  ["May-2013", 565603],
  ["Jun-2013", 872480],
  ["Jul-2013", 789480],
  ["Aug-2013", 999942],
  ["Sep-2013", -1196225],
  ["Oct-2013", 268997],
  ["Nov-2013", -687986],
  ["Dec-2013", 1150461],
  ["Jan-2014", 682458],
  ["Feb-2014", 617856],
  ["Mar-2014", 824098],
  ["Apr-2014", 581943],
  ["May-2014", 132864],
  ["Jun-2014", 448062],
  ["Jul-2014", 689161],
  ["Aug-2014", 800701],
  ["Sep-2014", 1166643],
  ["Oct-2014", 947333],
  ["Nov-2014", 578668],
  ["Dec-2014", 988505],
  ["Jan-2015", 1139715],
  ["Feb-2015", 1029471],
  ["Mar-2015", 687533],
  ["Apr-2015", -524626],
  ["May-2015", 158620],
  ["Jun-2015", 87795],
  ["Jul-2015", 423389],
  ["Aug-2015", 840723],
  ["Sep-2015", 568529],
  ["Oct-2015", 332067],
  ["Nov-2015", 989499],
  ["Dec-2015", 778237],
  ["Jan-2016", 650000],
  ["Feb-2016", -1100387],
  ["Mar-2016", -174946],
  ["Apr-2016", 757143],
  ["May-2016", 445709],
  ["Jun-2016", 712961],
  ["Jul-2016", -1163797],
  ["Aug-2016", 569899],
  ["Sep-2016", 768450],
  ["Oct-2016", 102685],
  ["Nov-2016", 795914],
  ["Dec-2016", 60988],
  ["Jan-2017", 138230],
  ["Feb-2017", 671099],
];

const calculateData = (array) => {
  let highestGain = -Infinity;
  let dateAndAmountGain = "";
  
  let worstGain = +Infinity;
  let dateAndAmountLose = "";
  
  let sum = array[0][1];
  let length = array.length;
  
  let totalGain = 0;
  let totalLose = 0;
  
  for (let i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
    const currentNumber = array[i];
    const currentMonth = currentNumber[0];
    const currentValue = currentNumber[1];
    
    const prevNumber = finances[i-1];
    const prevMonth = prevNumber[0];
    const prevValue = prevNumber[1];
    
    const diff = currentValue - prevValue;
    if (diff > highestGain) {
      highestGain = diff;
      dateAndAmountGain = `Greatest increase in profits \n Mouth \ \ Amount \n ${prevMonth} ${prevValue} \n ${currentMonth} ${currentValue}`;
    }
    
    if (diff < worstGain) {
      worstGain = diff;
      dateAndAmountLose = `Worst increase in profits \n Mouth \ \ Amount \n ${prevMonth} ${prevValue} \n ${currentMonth} ${currentValue}`;
    }
    
    sum += currentValue;
    
    if (currentValue > 0) {
      totalGain += currentValue;
    } else {
      totalLose += currentValue;
    }
  }
  console.log(dateAndAmountGain);
  console.log(dateAndAmountLose);
  console.log(`Average by month ${sum/length}`);
  console.log(`Total gain ${totalGain}. Total lose ${totalLose}`);
  
}
calculateData(finances);
```

I don't know where the data is being generated, but i think that the correct would be like this.

```js
const finances = [
 {date: "Jan-2010", value: 867884},
 {date: "Feb-2010", value: 984655},
]
```